# Go from trigform to complex form

Tags: waves, electric-circuits, electric-current, complex-numbers, linear-systems

I'm given the expression for a current as

$$\mathbf{I}=I_0\sin\omega t \ \hat{z}\tag1$$

and I want to write it in complex form. My professor just writes

$$\mathbf{I}=I_0\cos(\omega t-\pi/2) \ \hat{z}\implies\bar{\mathbf{I}}=I_0e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}}.\tag2$$

I'm totally clueless as to what he has done here after the implication. Can someone shed some light and fill in the steps there?

Comment: Basically when we write intensities or fields in an exponential notation we are just assuming that we take the real part of the complex number resultin from the new notation. Obviously it would make no sense to speak about an imaginary intensity but it would be too clumsy to always write $Re(I_0 e^{i\omega t})$ se we neglect it.

This laziness turns out to be mathematically fine because the complex exponential expression turns out to be a solution of Maxwell's equation even if a complex value for the field $E$ makes no sense.

Comment: so, to answer your question precisely. If you take the real part of the exponential expression you wrote and use Euler's formula it will be clear why the two are the same

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. I have that $I_0e^{-j\pi/2}=I_0(\cos{-\pi/2}+j\sin{-\pi/2})$ and the real part of this is just $I_0\cos{(-\pi/2})$, which misses the $\omega t$.

Comment: you are right I didn't read precisely what you wrote up there.

There is some confusing notation as the answer below pointed out.
That $\omega t$ has to end up somewhere so either you make the second expression $I_0e^{i(\omega t - \pi/2)}$. Or you can absorb the time-dependent part of the exponential into the constant just like @RobJeffries did below but in this case the $I_0$ in the first form is not the same as the one in the exponential form.

Comment: Often people use the overbar to indicate an average of some kind, which may be where your time dependence has gone. But of course the time average of a sine wave is zero... indeed, without the time dependence the implication doesn't really make a lot of sense. You may want to ask your professor (they may have made a mistake) or check your notes against someone else's.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly confusion over notation.

Since $j = \exp(j\pi/2)$ then multiplying by $\exp(-j\pi/2)$ just turns the imaginary part of a complex number into the real part of a new complex number that has been rotated through $\pi/2$ in the Argand diagram. In this case, turns $j\sin \omega t$ into $\sin \omega t$.

So I think equation 2 should be
$${\mathrm Im}(\mathbf{I})=I_0\cos(\omega t-\pi/2) \ \hat{z}\implies\bar{\mathbf{I}}=\mathbf{I}e^{-j\frac{\pi}{2}}.\tag2$$

Where $\bar{\mathbf{I}}$ is a complex number whose real part is what you are trying to physically represent.